# Julia not installing in Pycharm: 'requires plugin 'com.intellij.modules.java' to be installed

Tags: pycharm, julia

I have downloaded the Julia plugin for Pycharm. This should allow me to write Julia code in Pycharm. When I go to the settings/plugins, i see the following error:

```
 'requires plugin 'com.intellij.modules.java' to be installed
```

I have read that this package can be removed from the plugin.xml file, but i don't know where that .xml file is. How can this error be fixed?

Comment: where did you take it? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10413-julia ?

Comment: i just started using Juno instead